# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.google.android.gms.c.n.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: java, android

I am getting this exception from an Android App. If I leave the App running for an hour os so with no interaction it eventually throws this exception. I have no clue what so ever, what this can be related to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should post your code in order to help us in helping you

Comment: It is unlikely that this is a problem in your code. This exception sounds like a bug in the Play Services SDK.